# Formation Energy Calculations

Tags: density-functional-theory, formation-energy

How may I calculate each term of the formation energy equation using DFT?

I am assuming that for every software (i.e. Quantum ESPRESSO; Wien2k), the calculation procedure must be the same.

Comment: Where did you get this equation from? Is this about defect formation energy where $x$ means various possible defects? If so, then the formula doesn't look correct. Maybe it's missing something or to compact. Could you elaborate your equation? And lastly, in your 4th question, are you asking about what to keep in mind in defect formation energy calculation such as they did [here](https://journals.aps.org/prmaterials/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevMaterials.7.126201)?

Comment: +1, I suppose that OP meant E_f = E_compound - ∑(n_i * E_element_i), but I didn't change that unless he is explaining what he meant by his question. Besides, please follow the site policy of asking one question not a multiple, if you have other question you can do that seperately. thanks!

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin No, I am not talking about defects here right now. The equation was just a reference which I took from - https://docs.quantumatk.com/tutorials/formation_energies/formation_energies.html . I am essentially asking about how to do formation energy calculations?

Comment: @JaafarMehrez It is just one question regarding how to do formation energy?

Comment: @epsilon02fft The link you provided contains information about cohesive energy calculation (they termed it as formation energy) and defect formation energy calculation. Let me know if I get your question correctly: you are asking if your material has many constituents and they have lots of allotrope, which one to use for the last term of your equation, right?

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I have just been reading about it so I must have missed about the cohesive energy part, I apologise and I will edit it out. Yes. that is what I want to understand and the rest as asked if its optimized structures or any other details to keep in mind without getting any step wrong.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I wonder why you didn't remove the 2nd, 3rd and 4th questions based on [this policy](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5)? I didn't see the question until now because it was asked at around 4:30am in my time zone!

Comment: @NikeDattani I was trying to figure out the question and narrow the scope. It seems to me that all these questions are not much different questions. They can all be asked concisely by saying: how to calculate each term of the formation energy equation using DFT. Admittedly, then the scope of the question would be a little broad but I think all these can be addressed in a single post.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I also had mixed feelings because by the time I saw this post, all 4 of its constituent questions were answered, however the concern that I have is that we generally close posts that have more than 1 question in them, or look like they have more than one question in them, and it's possible that later someone has their post closed and uses this post as an **example** of why they feel that it was unfair that their post was closed. Ideally there would be consistency, which I think means having all question posts  containing only one question.

Comment: @NikeDattani I would like to reiterate that there were not 4 questions. It was just one question in which I just wanted to know specific parts. Now the new edited question will not give me the answer I want, I have searched it before. I am sorry, I feel like It is extremely hard to ask any questions here on the forum for a specific answer.

Comment: The original question certainly had more than one question mark, corresponding to more than one question. I edited the post based on the most recent comment by @AbdulMuhaymin which said that the question could be seen as just one all-encompassing question, and I put that question in the post. As for it being "extremely hard" to ask any questions here, it seems like you've asked 20 questions here, and all of them received answers except for 3 that are still open, and 2 that are closed (one of them you asked to get closed, and the other one was abandoned because you didn't reply to comments).

Comment: @NikeDattani But they were asking the specific parts of the same thing. I Should have made 4 different posts for same question with different parts? Maybe my wording was a bit misplaced here ("extremely hard"), as I still wanted to understand what do I have to do to ask just specific part for an answer for example just like the 1st and 4th part of the above question. As far as I remember I reply to every comments that I see here, if it was unintentionally missed then I will see to it.

Comment: You didn't reply to the question by Phil Hasnip on your zig-zag question. I'll let you find it rather than providing a link to it here. Anyway, I think that it would be more appropriate to ask a new question for each term of the formation energy equation, but @AbdulMuhaymin might have a different opinion. In general, when in doubt, I would recommend to err towards asking separate questions rather than asking questions that might look like they contain more than one sub-question. If someone only knows how to answer 1 question out of 4, then it messes up the system.

Comment: @NikeDattani Okay I got it. Thanks for your replies and suggestions. I will follow them properly. I hope my enquiries were not much of problems and I will see to it that they won't happen again.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what you want to investigate. Let's assume, we have a binary compound $A_nB_m$, the energy of formation could be

$$\Delta E_f = E(A_nB_m) - [ n E(A) + mE(B)]$$

where $E(A),E(B)$ are atomic energies. For the latter, one could put an isolated atom inside a large supercell and do a single point calculation. Or calculate the energy of a bulk elemental structure and divide its energy by the number of atoms.
They are not the same and the choice depends on the system. E.g. in a very diluted alloy it is probably okay to take single atomic energies. If there is a significant amount of $B$ inside the binary compound, other phases can occur and it is more useful to define the formation energy with respect to the energy of the pure phases. This means calculating the energy of the phase and dividing by the number of atoms. 
A formation energy (like defined above) cannot tell you much about thermodynamic stability. What does it tell you? If $\Delta E_F < 0 $, then the system is energetically favoring the binary compound configuration over whatever stays in square brackets. In other words, it will not separate into its pure compounds. Another formation energy could be the adsorption of a molecule onto a slab, then

$$\Delta E_f = E(slab+mol) - [E(slab) + E(mol)]$$

One can then compare different formation energies (for different concentrations of $A$ & $B$ above ) and plot them to see which concentration has the lowest energy. This is called Convex Hull plot. Or in the example with the molecule, put different molecules onto the surface and compare the formation energies. The comparison of formation energies has to be done with attention. For the slab functionalization, distance to the slab, functional groups, formation of covalent bonds, geometry of the molecules have to be comparable. The difference in formation energies can be in order of meV. For the case with the binary compound, one should keep in mind phase diagrams, which gives rise about the phase composition at a certain temperature and concentration.

1. You should use optimized structures. If your formation energy contains single atomic energies, where you want to calculate the energy of an isolated atom as a reference, I think you do not need an optimization. In this case the supercell should be large enough to avoid interactions between atoms ( due to periodic boundary condition).
2. It depends on what you calculate and on your system. I stated this above.
3. Run spin polarized calculations for cases, where you have magnetic moments. Maybe you have some insight from experiments or literature if the system is magnetic or not.  You have to find the magnetic moment on each atom. In Quantum ESPRESSO , one should use the nspin tag. You must initiate the calculation with a starting magnetization on some atoms, use the tag starting_magnetization(i) for this. Different starting magnetizations can lead to different ground states. I realized this myself. Find the configuration with lowest energy after the spin polarized calculation.
4. Your "hyperparameters", like cutoff energies, pseudo potentials, k-points, smearing etc. should be the same in the calculation of all energies. Only then energies are comparable. As i mentioned before, difference in formation energy can be at meV. So it is sensitive.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I think it answers what I wanted to know. The isolated atom calculation for a phase, spin calculation for the same, and the parameters for it should be same as for all calculations was the part I was missing